# How to convert a specific android project built with ant to gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, antbuilder

I am using [this](https://github.com/mmin18/AndroidDynamicLoader) framework for one of my projects and i have problems keeping it up to date. It is a little old, uses ant to build the components and is meant for eclipse. I usually use android studio and use gradle to build from interface(not command line).

The project has a host and plugins that are loaded from a server. The plugins are compiled from the command line cmd from windows using "tools/update.sh workspace" and "ant release" commands.

What i succeded so far:
I manually copyed the files from the host component and succeded without too much stroogle to do an android studio project and build it with no errors. And it succesfully loading the plugins.

On the plugin side I have to projects: for every new plugin i do a special android studio project and after everything is ok I adapt the code and copy it to a special template like eclipse project(i edit it with notepad++ no need for eclipse) and i build it with "ant release". That apk then i move it to server.

You see now that it is a little strange but somehow I made it to work. Problem is I'm always on the edge, I almost make it every time with little hacks to pass the build process. I think it is because i work in a mixed situation. I want to port everything on android studio and gradle. And hopefully build everything from the android studio command line.

The host builds in a jar file and is used in the plugin build.

I will put the new source code on request, till then you can see it in action [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.probitorg.stroogle)

To be more specific, the impassable bug appeared when i used MediaPlayer on the plugin. I had to move the wav files on the host witch is opposed to the framework design. But this is anyway the tip of the iceberg. So i would like to port everything from ant to gradle, and eclipse to android studio.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any existing project open in your Android Studio then just close that project. After your project is closed, it will show you a **Welcome screen popup**, there you can **select** `Import Project` option and it will automatically convert your project into Android Studio Project.

Here is what it will look like

[image]

Comment: The old project is in eclipse. And the problem is the projects are built using ant and some build.xml files from command line, so it's not that simple.

Comment: @powerbit did you gave it a try?

Comment: I tryed some time ago, it didn't found it as a project(i refer here to the plugin template written in eclipse) . I will try again tomorrow. But as I said, now I build them from windows command line with "ant release". What command will I do that will replace a lot of build.xml files which are not even in the plugin folder, so there will be no sense opening it in android studio.

Comment: Sorry but no success. It resulted in a big list of projects in the same place, and the play button is not activated whatever the context. How do i build them?